# how to incorporate some Persian rules as drop down lists in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a code that somehow resembles the Persian calendar. there are 3 drop down lists for year,month and day. here are the rules I'd like to include:

months 1 to 6 have 31 days
months 7 to 11 have 30 days
month 12 has 29 days
every 4 years, 12th month has 30 days(leap year)
if the user chooses on of the (1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6) months, the drop down list for days must have 31 days

if the user chooses on of the (7 - 8 - 9 - 10 - 11 ) months, the drop down list for days must have 30 days

if the user chooses the 12th month, the drop down list for days must have 29 days

if the user chooses one of (1375 – 1379 – 1383 – 1387 – 1391 – 1395) year and if he chooses the 12th month, the drop down list for days must have 30 days

here is the code I have written so far but my code doesn't work, please help me with it.

```
from tkinter import *

x=StringVar()

def ok():
    if months == months[0:5]:
     x = dayoptions1
    if months == months[6:10]:
     x = dayoptions2
    if months == months[11] and years == 1375 or 1379 or 1383 or 1387 or 1391 or 1395:
     x = dayoptions3


root = Tk()

label1 = Label(root, text="year",width=15)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

yearoptions = ["1397", "1396","1395","1394","1393","1392","1391","1390","1389","1388","1387","1386","1385","1384","1383","1382","1381","1380","1379","1378","1377","1376","1375"]
yearvariable = StringVar(root)
yearvariable.set(yearoptions[0])

years = OptionMenu(root, yearvariable, *yearoptions)
years.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5, pady=5)

label2 = Label(root, text="month",width=15)
label2.grid(row=0, column=2)

monthoptions = ["1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
monthvariable = StringVar(root)
monthvariable.set(monthoptions[0])

months = OptionMenu(root, monthvariable, *monthoptions)
months.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=5, pady=5)

label1 = Label(root, text="day",width=15)
label1.grid(row=0, column=4)

dayoptions1 = ["1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"]
dayoptions2 = ["1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30"]
dayoptions3 = ["1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29"]
dayvariable = StringVar(root)
dayvariable.set("1")

days = OptionMenu(root, dayvariable, *x)
days.grid(row=0,column=5,padx=5, pady=5)




root.mainloop()
```